# token_for_business is accessible only for the current user

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I get the following error from FB, I'm not really sure what I've done wrong. Many users are successfully logging in with FB so I'm not sure what happened in this case. I can't find anything about this error message on Google, does anyone have any idea?

`token_for_business is accessible only for the current user or the request must use an app access token and the user must have installed or have a role on the app`

Comment: Well have you checked if those quite specific requirements the message talks about are fulfilled in this case or not? Did you make the request for the current app user, using their user access token? Or did you try to use the app token, but the user has removed the app already?

Comment: @CBroe it's hard to tell – I got notified that this error happened on my server. There's only one place I do that and it's right after the user has successfully connected via FB, so I don't see why I'd get this error. It works well for hundreds of other users. That's why I'm asking on Stack Overflow to see if anyone else has experience this this specific error message.